# How Do I do a group by a sum in a list in Tray.io?

Tags: list, sum, integration, group, tray.io

I have a list like this

```
        {
            "user_email": "fakemail@icloud.com",
            "duration": 320
        },
        {
            "user_email": "badmail@gmail.com",
            "duration": 167,
        },
                {
            "user_email": "fakemail@icloud.com",
            "duration": 450
        }
```

and I need to build a new list groupig by user_mail and sum the duration

I need to obtain a list like this

```
        {
            "user_email": "badmail@gmail.com",
            "duration": 167,
        },
                {
            "user_email": "fakemail@icloud.com",
            "duration": 770
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would complete that transformation with a Tray.io script step containing the following code:

```
exports.step = function(input, fileInput) {
  const data = input.data;
  const result = {};
  
  data.forEach(entry => {
    const userEmail = entry.user_email;
    const duration = entry.duration;
    if (result.hasOwnProperty(userEmail)) {
      result[userEmail] += duration;
    } else {
      result[userEmail] = duration;
    }
  });
  
  const outputData = Object.keys(result).map(userEmail => ({
    user_email: userEmail,
    duration: result[userEmail],
  }));

  return outputData; 
}
```

The original array of objects is passed as "data" on the input.

[Resulting script output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LJDBa.png)

[Script step and input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HaBY2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing this in a JavaScript/Node environment, you can reduce the objects into a `Map` and then map the resulting entries back into an array.

Here is a very functional approach to achieve this:

```js
const exports = {};

exports.step = (input, fileInput) =>
  [...input.data
    .reduce((map, { user_email, duration }) =>
      map.set(user_email, (map.get(user_email) ?? 0) + duration), new Map)
    .entries()]
    .map(([user_email, duration]) => ({ user_email, duration }));

const input = {
  data: [
    { "user_email": "fakemail@icloud.com" , "duration": 320 },
    { "user_email": "badmail@gmail.com"   , "duration": 167 },
    { "user_email": "fakemail@icloud.com" , "duration": 450 }
  ]
};

const output = exports.step(input);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```